# How to embed html file in dll and edit the content later?

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, dll

I don't have enough idea on how to work with this.

Objective:
1) Embed HTML file in dll

- Content of the html would be:

  ### Good Day!

  You received this email because a request was made for password retrieval with this email address.
  Please go to the link below to start the process:

  Click the link below 
  BaseUrl{}

  Please ignore this email if you did not make such request.

  Best,
  Web Master

2) Everytime I have to send this email, I have to find and replace the "**BaseUrl{}**" with a link for verification inside the embeded html.

3) I have to send the file in a form of html file, beacause in further development, I will have to put images in the file.

Code for sending email:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public static void SendEmail(MailMessage mail)
{
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.Port = 123;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@mail.com", "strongpassword");
client.EnableSsl = true;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
client.Send(mail);

}  


private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)  
{
if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    return true;
else
{
    ServiceFault.WriteLog("Invalid SSL");
    return true;
}
}
```

Or you can give me links for tutorial, or if you have more better suggestion, please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the strategy of using string replacement for the URI is fine.

In order to embed this into you DLL:

1) Create a file with the content you want. 
2) Add a Resources file to your project.
3) Add a "File" type resource (the Add Existing File option) and select your file (which will copy your file into your project.
4) In your code, access the content of that embedded file using the auto-generate resource accessor.

Comment: this works for me, plus adding the Replace method to insert the link, problem solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. To embed a file into your DLL (and I'm assuming you are using Visual Studio), in the "Solution Explorer" tab, right click on the project or a folder and go `Add->Existing Item...` and then add your file to the solution.  From there, right click on the file and click "Properties".  From there, choose "Embedded Resource" for the "Build Action" property
   From there, you can read the file in as a string.
2. I would change "BaseUrl{}" to `{0}` and if you read the file in as a string, use this code to do a replace:

   ```
   string email = string.Format(emailText, baseUrl);
   ```

   From there you can add the `email` string as your message and all is good!
3. That looks like it should work!

Comment: This would copy the file with the distribution (assuming the correct "Compile Action" is set but wouldn't bundle it inside a dll. For that, you'd have to add it specifically as a resource